# monitor and mutex synchronization in c

Tags: mutex, monitor

I will implement merge sort using mutexes and monitors in C but I couldn't find a good        source. How can I implement mutex and monitor in C.

I am using Linux(Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Inter process communication (IPC) is supported by operation system. In linux you are given pthread library and System V semaphores.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

http://nitish712.blogspot.com/2012/09/system-v-ipcsemaphores.html

Unless you say what operating system you use, there is not much more help you can get.